# Solving Matrix Equations with Extra Vector Term

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

How does one solve an equation of the form $$\vec{x} = A \vec{a} + \vec{b} $$? 
Naturally if one wants to solve $$\vec{x} = A \vec{a}$$, we compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$, but what do we do about the extra $\vec{b} $ term?

**edit**
I really mean to discuss equations of the form $$\vec{y}^{`} = A \vec{y} + \vec{b} $$

That is, a system of first order linear differential equations with some forcing vector $[0,0,0,\cdots,f(t)]$.

Answer (score 1):

If you solve $\dot y=Ay+b$, where $A$ is a constant matrix, then you have quite a variety of different methods. The simpliest one is representing $y(t)=e^{At}z(t)$ and then writing

$$\dot y = Ay+e^{At}\dot z(t)=Ay+b(t),$$
or $$z(t)=\int_{t_0}^te^{-As}b(s)ds+z(t_0).$$
Therefore,
$$y(t) = e^{A(t-t_0)}y(t_0)+\int_{t_0}^te^{A(t-s)}b(s)ds.$$

Comment: why is $y = e^{At}z(t)$?

Comment: @AnthonyPeter because we chose so. In fact, it comes from solving the homogenous equation $\dot y=Ay$, which has a solution $y(t)=e^{At}c$, where $c$ is a constant vector. Then we apply the method of variation of constant.